# Apache custom error pages

Tags: apache-2.2, html

Is there a way to make apache redirect error codes (401 particularly) to a custom page?

I tried using "ErrorDocument 401 /errors/somepage.html" in the htaccess file but its not working.
Any other ways of doing that?

Oh - I don't have access to httpd.conf :>

Comment: You should be able to get from your hosting provider which settings you are able to override in an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have been granted the appropriate `override` in the httpd.conf you will be able to do it in .htaccess.  If you don't have that override permission you won't be able to do it without access to the httpd.conf.

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

in the  section of the httpd.conf for your site will grant you the permission to set error pages in .htaccess.  If there is already an AllowOverride entry then add FileInfo to the existing one.

Contact the person who has control over the httpd.conf file and ask if they will add that permission.